# PHP not storing data in sessions for some users

Tags: php, linux, session

An internal server serves two different applications to users on our LAN:

```
https://10.0.0.100/app1/
https://10.0.0.100/app2/
```

Both apps are served by the same Apache config file, they are just in separate directories under `public_html`. Both apps use PHP sessions, but they both prefix the `$_SESSION` variables with their namespaces:

```
$_SESSION['app1_favorite_colour'] = 'Yellow';
$_SESSION['app2_quest'] = 'Agghhh!';
```

Despite this, **users who are logged into `app1` are not having their `app2_` session data written to the session file on disk**. Consider `page1.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * App2
 * /page1.php
 */

session_start();
$_SESSION['apps_been_here'] = 'Yes!';
echo "<a href='page2.php'>Clicky</a>";

?>
```

Then, on `page2.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * App2
 * /page2.php
 */

session_start();
echo "Have you been here: {$_SESSION['apps_been_here']}";
```

This does **not** print "yes" to the user if the user is logged into app1 as well! However, users who don't use app1 **do** see "yes" on `page2.php`. Investigating, I opened the session files in `/var/lib/php/session/`. I see only variables in that file that begin with the prefix `app1_` and none that begin with `app2_` *for users who are logged into app1*. Other users who are not logged into app1 *do* have variables what begin with `app2_` in their session files!

I have checked with `lsof` that the files are not locked and I have confirmed that there are no open browser windows running `app1` pages in the browser. **Why might the App2 session variables not be stored to the session file?** There is plenty of free memory and hard drive space, and the CPU load is under 0.1 (as measured by `uptime`). Theproblem happens for multiple users in multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome). Clearing browser cookies and cache does not help.

Comment: What did you do in App1 login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are doing should work but there is a better way to do it that may fix your problem in your case.
Instead of prefixing your session keys with 'app1' or 'app2' just use the [session_name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)() function before session_start() like:

```
session_name('app1');
session_start();
$_SESSION['been_here'] = 'Yes!';
...
```

You can also adjust the session cookie path with [session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)() so both apps would be completely invisible to each other like:
    session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24*30, '/app1/');

For further troubleshooting you should examine everywhere you're using session_* functions and look at the [session.*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) config options in your php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['apps_been_here'] = 'Yes!';
echo "<a href='page2.php'>Clicky</a>";
session_write_close();
```

I had an issue like that once. That fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

not good they must be in same sub tree
you need to have

- root/

  - myapp/
  - - session.php
  - - app1/
  - - app2/

session.php  will contain only session_start();

each app1 & app2 will include session.php ( require_once("../session.php"); )
this is the only way that I know to make them work